# SmtpClient always times out when sending email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp

It doesn't matter if I use gmail, mandrill, sendgrid, ssl, or not ssl

After somewhere between 1-20 successful emails (for whatever configuration I'm trying), every request begins timing out.

Here's my code:

```
var fromAddressObj = new MailAddress("contact@site.fm", "site");
var toAddressObj = new MailAddress(toAddress, toAddress); // toAddress
const string fromPassword = "password";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
   {
      Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net", 
      Port = 587, EnableSsl = false, 
      DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, 
      UseDefaultCredentials = false, 
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddressObj.Address, fromPassword)
   };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddressObj, toAddressObj){Subject = subject, Body = body})
{
   try
   {
      smtp.Send(message);
   }
   catch
   {
      return;
      //
   }   
}
```

Why would this be happening?

Note : I have no firewall / antivirus that could be getting in the way that I know of... unless default windows settings somehow throttle outbound requests to SMTP servers?

I'm totally at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried simply putting a breakpoint in your catch statement and trying the Send again just when it fails?  In my experience I have had issues where Send fails intermittently but succeeds immediately afterwards on retry.

Comment: It's quite possible your ISP and/or the server you're hosting the site on will throttle a lot of outbound SMTP requests in a short amount of time